# Oracle Trigger: update table2 after inserting on table 1

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-update, where-clause, sql-insert

I have the following trigger but It's not working, I don't get any error, it simply doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROYECTO.ACTUALIZAPRECIOSTOTALFACTURA
AFTER INSERT
ON PROYECTO.DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    update DOCUMENTOS
    set doc_total=doc_total+:new.doc_det_precio
    where doc_numero = :new.doc_numero;
END;
```

If I delete the "where" condition, it does work, but not the way I need (it adds the doc_det_precio on documentos.doc_total but in the firt record I have on the DOCUMENTOS table, always. What should I be doing wrong?

Tables are:
**DOCUMENTOS**
DOC_numero
DOC_total

**DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE**
DOC_DET_id
DOC_numero
DOC_DET_precio

Answer (score 0):

Should your `where` clause be:

```
where doc_numero = :new.doc_det_doc_numero;
```

You might also want to re-consider trying to keep the sum up to date on the master table. It can easily fall out of synch.  Often it is more appropriate to just compute the total when needed:

```
select m.doc_numero
      ,sum(d.doc_det_precio) as doc_total
  from documentos m
  join documentos_detalle d on (d.doc_numero = m.doc_numero)
  group by m.doc_numero
```

Comment: Sorry, both fields are named the same in both tables, I just edited the question. Do you think that could affect the result?

Comment: It is not a schema issue, is it? You are running everything from within the `PROYECTO` schema? Otherwise you might not be updating the table you think (since `DOCUMENTOS` is not prefixed by the schema. I would remove all schema references.  And you have the primary key on DOCUMENTOS.DOC_numero and a foreign key on DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE.DOC_numero?

Comment: HI Glenn. Thanks for your answers. Regarding the original question, It is not a schema issue, I have tried running with and without the schema prefix (all the tables) but nothing. And yes, the DOCUMENTOS.Doc_numero is a FK on DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE.Doc_numero. The weird thing is that my code works without the WHERE condition, and I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong. I also tried your first script (select) and it works, now I'm trying to put it on a trigger, I really need to do it the way I was first trying to do it.

Comment: It looks right too me.  I just tried it on sqlfiddle.  Take a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57905/1

Comment: It's created OK, but it simply doesn't do anything. Now, if trying to do your SELECT and SUM code, I'm trying to do it withing a trigger, I get the error "DOCUMENTOS cannot be used as an into-target of a select statement". My code is:                      CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTUALIZAPRECIOSTOTALFACTURA
AFTER INSERT
ON DOCUMENTOS_DETALLE
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  select (sum(DOC_DET_PRECIO))
  INTO DOCUMENTOS
  from documentos_detalle 
  join documentos  on (documentos.DOC_NUMERO=documentos_detalle.DOC_NUMERO);
END;

Comment: If doing the sum, you don't need a trigger.  Just do your inserts, then run the query to compute the sum. I updated the query with the group by and updated the sqlfiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57905/6/0